# Rust's borrow-checker, for loop and structs methods

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm struggling to find a solution for the error in the code below:

```
struct Cell {
    line: u8,
    column: u8,
    square: u8,
    value: u8,
}


struct Sudoku {
    cells: Vec<Cell>,
}

impl Sudoku {
    
    fn possible_values(&self, cell: &Cell) -> Vec<u8> {
        ...
    }

    fn solve(&mut self) {
        for cell in self.cells.iter_mut() {
            if cell.value == 0 {
                let possible_values = self.possible_values(&cell);
                match possible_values.len() {
                    0 => panic!("La résolution semble impossible"),
                    1 => {
                        cell.value = possible_values[0];
                        println!("In cell {:?} I would write {}", cell, possible_values[0]);
                    }
                    _ => (),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
```

`for mut cell in self.cells.iter_mut()` (on self: mutable borrow occurs here and mutable borrow later used here

`let possible_values = self.possible_values(&cell);`  (on self: immutable borrow occurs here  )

The function `possible_values` borrows `self` (not mutable).

The for loop needs an `iter_mut()` because I want to change `cell.value`, but I also need to use the `possible_values` function to get the value I want to assign to `cell.value`.
How can I manage do do that?

[Here is the code.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=25f035456a06340ae5f2153a925145a6)

Comment: The borrowck error is quite self-explanatory, I believe. To help you more we need to know what `possible_values()` needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the `mut` from `for mut case`.

An example from the docs:

```
// Then, we iterate over it and increment each element value:
for element in slice.iter_mut() {
    *element += 1;
}
```

Comment: I can confirm this works

Comment: Indeed, the `mut` is useless, but it doesn't solve my problem  :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the borrow checker by identifying the cell by its index instead of holding a reference.

```
for i in 0..81 {
    if self.cells[i].value == 0 {
        let possible_values = self.possible_values(&self.cells[i]);
        match possible_values.len() {
            0 => panic!("La résolution semble impossible"),
            1 => {
                self.cells[i].value = possible_values[0];
                println!(
                    "In cell {:?} I would write {}",
                    self.cells[i], possible_values[0]
                );
            }
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9b5206cbfde6511332aa554e46d35f7a)